# Custom TableViewColumn delegate problems

Tags: qt, qml

I have several problems with a custom delegate for a `TableViewColumn`. Here is my `TreeView:`

```
    TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        model: fileSystemModel
        rootIndex: rootPathIndex
        selection: sel
        selectionMode: 2

        TableViewColumn {
            id: namecolumn
            title: "Name"
            role: "fileName"

            resizable: true
            width: parent.width-sizeWidth-dateWidth-scrollBarWidth
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
                id: fileCheckDelegate
                Row{

                    CheckBox{
                        id: cbox

                          visible: (model.isDir==true) ? false : true

                    }
                    Text{
                        id: itext
                        text: model.fileName
                        width: namecolumn.width-itext.x-cbox.width
                        elide: Text.ElideRight

                    }
                 }
                ToolTip {
                    parent: fileCheckDelegate
                    visible: hovered
                    delay: 1000
                    text: qsTr(model.fileName)
                }
            }

        }
        TableViewColumn {
            id: sizecolumn
            title: "Size"
            role: "size"

            resizable: false
            width: sizeWidth

        }

        TableViewColumn {
            id: datecolumn
            title: "Date Modified"
            role: "lastModified"
            width: dateWidth
            resizable: false

        }
    }
```

The problems can be seen in the image below:

- The filenames do not get truncated, although I thought the custom delegate should calculate the width so that elide is adding ellipsis. What is wrong with my calculation?
- The CheckBox is not centered vertically, how can this be accomplished? Edit: The solution in the comments works good enough
- My custom delegate does not have the alternating background color. How can I achive this?
- Also, if an Item is selected, my custom delegate does not have the highlight color. This is especially weird, as when I use my delegate in e.g. the Qt TableView example, the delegate also receives the highlight color. It might have something to do with me mixing Controls 1.4 and 2.4?

Thanks for your help,

[image: The TreeView with problems]

Comment: try ``anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter`` by your CheckBox

Comment: for some reason this does not work. however, I found anchors.baseline: itext.baseline to be working

Comment: You should set [Item.clip: true](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#clip-prop) for the filename column I guess.

Comment: for the background color use a javascript function. Use the modulus of the 'index' role provided from the model to select a color.